# Why am I getting the error Error Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=11 "<unknown>"?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to connect to a hardware device using NEHotspotConfigurationManager on an iPhone XR.  I have successfully connected on many different networks, but on my home network, it is failing with the error code 11, which is unknown.  Does anyone know what this means?

I have tried restarting my iPhone, but that didn't help. I've also verified it has nothing to do with the hardware device by setting the ssidPrefix to something random, but again, that made no difference.

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let config = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssidPrefix: "mySsidPrefix")
    NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(config) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            // handle error

        } else {
            // connect to device

        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works on all networks I have tried, but does not on my home network.  I have Comcast and I am using an Arris modem with Google WiFi mesh routers.

EDIT: This actually isn't just happening on my home network. I disconnected from WiFi and it's still happening.